Cannot reset password for the root user in MySQL
I’m trying to install and setup MySQL on my Machine (MacBook Pro M3 Max with Sonoma 14.5 OS) but it is not being possible to login anymore. The root password keep being changed after I shut down the machine and turn it on on the next day.
When I run the the mysql_secure_installation command and try to setup a password, the following access denied error happens:
$ mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I’ve tried to change the password for the root user by executing
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables 

, then
mysql -root

, then the commands to reset the password, but it says that a mysqld process already exists, which blocks the execution of further commands.
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

2024-07-04T17:57:49.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/Victors-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
2024-07-04T17:57:49.6NZ mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists

↳ This error is happening even after I kill all the mysqld and mysql processes with
sudo kill -9

or
sudo pkill -9 mysqld

or
sudo killall -9 mysqld

or
sudo killall -9 mysqld_safe 

or listing all the processes with
ps aux | grep mysql  

and killing each one of them manually via
sudo kill -9 <process_id>

So, in the end, I can’t use MySQL at all on my machine due to this login issue. Could someone help me? Thank you!

have you even tried to search for it https://gist.github.com/zubaer-ahammed/c81c9a0e37adc1cb9a6cdc61c4190f52

@nbk, yes, please read my full question. I already tried this solution, but it didn’t work.

killing the processes will not work as the service starts  over again read the git page very carefully and try to follow their recomendation by the letter

Just to let everyone that reads this know. People from mariadb com solved it https://tinyurl.com/bd95uj83. I would like to congratulate the support of the mariadb community. If someone if facing the same issue as me, please check this link.

so answer your question by yourself and accept it

I know, but why do you have to be so rude? Let's get to the facts: You provided an answer that I had already tried before and explicitly described on my question, which probably means you didn't even took a time to read my full question at your first look. Still, you didn't even apologize, edited my question changing formatting to please your desires and keep acting rudely throughout your answers.

Just to let everyone know, here is the solution to this issue that can happen in MacOS Sonoma 14.5.
Remove the mysql
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql

Install MariaDB
mariadb-install-db --user=$(whoami) --basedir="$(brew --prefix mariadb)" --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql

Login as root
sudo mysql -uroot

Change root password
set password = password("password");
exit

Now you can connect with MariaDB by mariadb -u root -ppassword anytime you want
